# Reduce spacing of frac in R expression for ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I am trying to reduce the space between the numerator, denominator, and fraction line in R expression.
Here is my MWE generating a very ugly legend text for the fraction:

```
tibble(
  t = seq(0,60,.1),
  osc = cos(log2(1+t)*pi+pi/4)
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(t, osc))+
  geom_line(aes(color = 'red'))+
  scale_color_manual(values = 'red', labels = expression(cos(log[2](t+1)*pi+frac(pi,4))+10))+
  theme(
    legend.position = 'bottom'
  )
```

The fraction introduces huge white space between the fraction line and numerator and denominator. Is there anyway to reduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to control spacing in plotmath, but you could use `paste(pi,"/",4)` instead of `frac(pi, 4)`:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Naw, if I were to rewrite the equation, I would probably put `pi*4^{-1}` or `phantom('')^pi/phantom('')[4]` if I would have wanted a slash. That was not my interest in posting this question.

Comment: I thought you *didn't* want ugly text in your legend.

Comment: I thought I wanted to reduce the space of the fraction, as per the first and last sentence.